# Triger image modal

Tags: image, bootstrap-modal

Good morning to all!

I run through a weird problem that I don't know what is wrong. I am uploading an image for each entry in the database. I am uploading the image name to the database and the image is successfully sent to directory I want.

Now is the tricky part of it. I have created a modal that recalls that image. The same modal is working perfectly in another page I use but not in that one.

```
<a href="#zoom" data-target="#zoom" data-toggle="modal" style="color:black;" class="small-box-footer" src="../dist/delivery_notes/<?php echo $row['del_note'];?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate text-blue" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

The modal that is called is the following:

```
<!--delivery notes zoom Modal Start--> 
<div id="zoom" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#zoom" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="height:auto" style="width:auto">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Product Photo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="" id="prod_pic">  
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>      
        </div>

        </div><!--end of modal-dialog-->
 </div>
 <!--end of zoom modal-->
```

My problem is that the modal is trigered but is not showing the image. It is blank. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.

The image is blank because your src is set as blank and you don't set or amend it.

Also there is no need for the #zoom in the href. As such you can amend your anchor tag to the following:

```
<a href="javascript:;" data-target="#zoom" data-toggle="modal" style="color:black;" class="small-box-footer" rel="../dist/delivery_notes/<?php echo $row['del_note'];?>" onclick="changeImage(this)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate text-blue" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

And then add the following JavaScript :

```
   <script>

function changeImage(elem){
document.getElementById("prod_pic").src = elem.rel;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help. I have the exact same code to another page that does the same thing with the difference that in the other page the image is showing small and i use a button to trigger the modal and "zoom" it. I will try this and I ll let you know!

Comment: Same problem... Does not show the image... i am curious on how it works in one page and not in the other though...

Comment: @juamx214 Wait a minute... Does it show anything? i.e. does it show the close button etc? Additionally, is this new page in a different sub-folder or directory from the one in which it works?

Comment: It is showing all the modal. The header the body (but is empty) and the footer with the close button. No they are in the same folder and the the folder that the images are stored in in the same sub-folder like the other one. With your proposal is showing the broken image icon..

Comment: @juamx214 I have updated my answer and verified it is working. It seemed to be a problem with src being assigned to an a tag instead of an img tag. Please update both the anchor AND the script to see it working.

Comment: because I have not used modal with javascript before, i need to use the script in the modal or prior? Is this to replace the src=""? Sory for asking that many questions!

Comment: Place all of the second part (the script tags) at the end of your file. Yes, rel will replace src.

Comment: hm so in the modal body the image anchor tag will be ' <img class="img-responsive" id="prod_pic">' ?

Comment: @juamx214 No, there are no changes needed to the modal.

Comment: it worked! Finally i was burning my brain for 5 hours for this! I appreciate it!

Comment: @juamx214 Happy to help!